# Create separate row for each item when merging multiple workbooks

Tags: vba, excel

I have several hundred spreadsheets that I would like to combine into a single master sheet.  Each spreadsheet contains general description information in several sells, and then a list of parts with columns of information that are specific to each part, as shown:
[image]

In the master sheet, I want a separate line for each part that includes the general information as well as the specific part information, as shown:
[image]

I have created a loop that pulls all the information I want, but all the information is written as a single line in the master sheet, as shown:
[image]

Can anyone tell me how to create a separate line for each item?  The code I have pieced together is shown- I think the solution to my problem lies in how to format the section titled "change this range to fit your own needs"

```
Sub MergeNT154BatchCards()
Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
Dim MyFiles() As String
Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet

Dim dt As String
Dim bookName As String

Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long
Dim a As Range, c As Range
Dim x As Long

Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range

' Change this to the path\folder location of your files.
MyPath = "C:\Users\amiller\OneDrive - CoorsTek\temp"

' Add a slash at the end of the path if needed.
If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
    MyPath = MyPath & "\"
End If

' If there are no Excel files in the folder, exit.
FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xls*")
If FilesInPath = "" Then
    MsgBox "No files found"
    Exit Sub
End If

' Fill the myFiles array with the list of Excel files
' in the search folder.
FNum = 0
Do While FilesInPath <> ""
    FNum = FNum + 1
    ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
    MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
    FilesInPath = Dir()
Loop

' Set various application properties.
With Application
    CalcMode = .Calculation
    .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Add a new workbook with one sheet.
Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Density"
    bookName = "DensitySummary"
    dt = Format(CStr(Now), "yyyy_mm_dd_hh.mm")
    BaseWks.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\amiller\OneDrive - CoorsTek\temp\" & bookName & dt
rnum = 1

Range("A1").Value = "FileName"
Range("B1").Value = "Description"
Range("C1").Value = "WaterTemp(C)"
Range("D1").Value = "WaterDensity(g/cc)"
Range("E1").Value = "PartID"
Range("F1").Value = "DryMass(g)"
Range("G1").Value = "SuspendedMass(g)"
Range("H1").Value = "Density(g/cc)"

' Loop through all files in the myFiles array.
If FNum > 0 Then
    For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
        Set mybook = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
        On Error GoTo 0

        If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
            On Error Resume Next

            ' Change this range to fit your own needs.
            With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                Set R1 = Range("A11, A5, B5")
                Set R2 = Range("A13:D" & Range("A13").End(xlDown).Row)
                Set RF = Union(R1, R2)
                Set sourceRange = RF

            End With

            If Err.Number > 0 Then
                Err.Clear
                Set sourceRange = Nothing
            Else

                ' If source range uses all columns then
                ' skip this file.
                If sourceRange.Columns.Count >= BaseWks.Columns.Count Then
                    Set sourceRange = Nothing
                End If
            End If
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not sourceRange Is Nothing Then

                SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                    MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                    GoTo ExitTheSub
                Else

                    ' Copy the file name in column A.
                    With sourceRange
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "A"). _
                                Resize(.Rows.Count).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                    End With

                    ' Set the destination range.
                    Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("B" & rnum + 1)

                    x = 0
                    For Each a In sourceRange.Areas
                        For Each c In a.Cells
                            x = x + 1
                            destrange.Offset(0, x - 1).Value = c.Value
                        Next c
                    Next a

                    ' Copy the values from the source range
                    ' to the destination range.
                    With sourceRange
                        Set destrange = destrange. _
                                        Resize(.Rows.Count, .Columns.Count)
                    End With
                    destrange.Value = sourceRange.Value

                    rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                End If
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False
        End If

    Next FNum
    BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
End If

ExitTheSub:
    ' Restore the application properties.
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Start writing to a new row in the master sheet every time you process a new row in the source sheet.  (Without seeing your code, that's about the best I can suggest.)  To create a MCVE, take a copy of your code and delete all the lines that have nothing to do with your problem.  Run what you end up with just to make sure it still does what you illustrate in the question, and then post that code.

Comment: Thanks for the comment- I've included a condensed version of the code.  I'm not sure if my problem might be in the section that selects the data from the original work sheets ("change this range to fit your own needs") or in the section that writes the data to a new sheet ("copy the values from the source range to the destination range").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm slightly worried because the headings you seem to be writing to the master sheet don't seem to line up with the data, and because you seem to be only copying `Range("A11, A5, B5")` from the top part of each sheet but your images show 5 fields being taken from the top, but I **think** you can replace your `For FNum` loop with the following:

```
For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
    Set mybook = Nothing
    On Error Resume Next
    Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
    On Error GoTo 0

    If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
        With mybook.Worksheets(1)
            Set SourceRange = .Range("A13:D" & .Range("A13").End(xlDown).Row)

            SourceRcount = SourceRange.Rows.Count

            If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            Else

                ' Copy the file name in column A.
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "A").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                ' Copy information such as date/time started, start/final temp, and Batch ID
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "B").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("A4").Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "C").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("B4").Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "D").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("A5").Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "E").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("A5").Value
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "F").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("A11").Value
                'Copy main data
                BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "G").Resize(SourceRcount, SourceRange.Columns.Count).Value = SourceRange.Value

                rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
            End If
        End With
    End If
    mybook.Close savechanges:=False
Next FNum
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed, THANK YOU!  And thanks for having the patience to work through my sloppy question.  You were right; the code I posted (only copying A11, A5, and B5) was for an older format.

Comment: FYI- I had to swap the order of the code from at the end from `End If, End If, End With` to `End If, End With, End If` but everything else worked perfectly!

Comment: Thanks for picking up the incorrect order.  I have edited the answer accordingly.  ([Mat's Mug](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1188513/mats-mug) will probably come along now and remind me that that wouldn't have happened if I had had [RubberDuck](http://rubberduckvba.com/) installed, and he would be right.)

Answer (score 1):

The root of your problem is that you are trying to do too much in a single subroutine.  Whenever your subroutines are over 25-40 lines, you should consider extracting functionality into smaller subroutines.  In this way, you will be able to test smaller portions of code at a time.

By implementing this strategy, I managed to reduce the OPs original subroutine from 152 lines of code to 5 easy to debug subroutines with 80 lines of code.

1. MergeNT154BatchCards - Main subroutine
2. AddBatchCard - Opens a Workbook and adds new rows of data to a range
3. getDensityTemplate - Creates a new Workbook based off a template
4. getFileList - Gets a list of file from a directory
5. ToggleEvents - Turns off and on events and returns the current Calculation mode

I haven't tested some parts of the code and as @YowE3K stated the headers don't line up.  I would think that it will be fairly easy to modify the code to fit the OPs requirement using these smaller blocks of code.

---

```
Public Sub MergeNT154BatchCards()
    Dim vFiles As Variant, FileFullName As Variant
    Dim NextRow As Range, wb As Workbook
    Dim CalculationMode As XlCalculation
    CalculationMode = ToggleEvents(False, xlCalculationManual)

    vFiles = getFileList("C:\Users\best buy\Downloads\stackoverfow", "*.xls*")
    If UBound(vFiles) = -1 Then
        MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, ""
        Exit Sub
    End If

    Set wb = getDensityTemplate

    For Each FileFullName In vFiles
        With wb.Worksheets(1)
            'Add Header
            .Range("A1:H1").Value = Array("FileName", "Description", "WaterTemp(C)", "WaterDensity(g/cc)", "PartID", "DryMass(g)", "SuspendedMass(g)", "Density(g/cc)")
            'Target the next empty row
            Set NextRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
            AddBatchCard CStr(FileFullName), NextRow
        End With
    Next

    ToggleEvents True, CalculationMode
End Sub

Private Sub AddBatchCard(FileFullName As String, NextRow As Range)
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim x As Long, y As Long
    With Workbooks.Open(FileFullName)
        With .Worksheets(1)
            For Each cell In .Range("A13", .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Value
                'NextRow
                NextRow.Cells(1, 1).Value = .Range("A4").Value
                NextRow.Cells(1, 2).Value = .Range("B4").Value
                NextRow.Cells(1, 3).Value = .Range("A5").Value
                NextRow.Cells(1, 4).Value = .Range("B5").Value
                NextRow.Cells(1, 4).Resize(1, 4).Value = cell.Resize(1, 4).Value
                Set NextRow = NextRow.Offset(1)
            Next
        End With
        .Close SaveChanges:=False
    End With
End Sub

Private Function getDensityTemplate(FilePath As String) As Workbook
    Dim SheetsInNewWorkbook As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    SheetsInNewWorkbook = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
    Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

    Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
    wb.Worksheets(1).Name = "Density"
    wb.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "DensitySummary" & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd_hh.mm")
    Set getDensityTemplate = wb
End Function

Private Function getFileList(FilePath As String, PatternSearch As String) As Variant
    Dim FileName As String
    If Right(FilePath, 1) <> "\" Then FilePath = FilePath & "\"

    With CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
        FileName = Dir(FilePath & PatternSearch)
        Do While FileName <> ""
            .Add FilePath & FileName
            FileName = Dir()
        Loop
        getFileList = .ToArray
    End With
End Function

Private Function ToggleEvents(EnabelEvents As Boolean, CalculationMode As XlCalculation) As XlCalculation
    With Application
        ToggleEvents = .Calculation
        .Calculation = CalculationMode
        .ScreenUpdating = EnabelEvents
        .EnableEvents = EnabelEvents
    End With
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you for doing this.  I have very little experience with VBA, so I appreciate any advice I can get.  This solution is much more elegant than my brute force approach... and much easier to understand.  I will have to make some minor tweaks, but your code will be a great template for projects in the future!