# "Argument not optional" error when running sub

Tags: vba

When I try to run a sub (below), I get the compile error: argument not optional, at the line `Set wb = getDensityTemplate()`.  Can anyone explain this to me?  Thanks Thomas Inzina for providing this code for me.

```
Public Sub MultipleParts()
Dim vFiles As Variant, FileFullName As Variant
Dim NextRow As Range, wb As Workbook
Dim CalculationMode As XlCalculation
CalculationMode = ToggleEvents(False, xlCalculationManual)

vFiles = getFileList("C:\Users\OneDrive-CoorsTek\temp", "*.xls*")
If UBound(vFiles) = -1 Then
    MsgBox "No files found", vbInformation, ""
    Exit Sub
End If

Set wb = getDensityTemplate()

For Each FileFullName In vFiles
    With wb.Worksheets(1)
        'Add Header
        .Range("A1:H1").Value = Array("FileName", "Description", "WaterTemp(C)", "WaterDensity(g/cc)", "PartID", "DryMass(g)", "SuspendedMass(g)", "Density(g/cc)")
        'Target the next empty row
        Set NextRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
        AddBatchCard CStr(FileFullName), NextRow
    End With
Next

ToggleEvents True, CalculationMode 
End Sub
```

The `getDensityTemplate` sub is also shown.

```
Private Function getDensityTemplate(FilePath As String) As Workbook
Dim SheetsInNewWorkbook As Integer
Dim wb As Workbook
SheetsInNewWorkbook = Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook
Application.SheetsInNewWorkbook = 1

Set wb = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet)
wb.Worksheets(1).Name = "Density"
wb.SaveAs FileName:=FilePath & "DensitySummary" & Format(Now, "yyyy_mm_dd_hh.mm")
Set getDensityTemplate = wb
```

End Function

Comment: look like its missing an argument... can you update your question with the getDensityTemplate sub listed

Comment: Can you post the code for getDensityTemplate?

Comment: According the this page, it seems that you need to pass it a string for its filepath. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718110/create-separate-row-for-each-item-when-merging-multiple-workbooks

Comment: The question has been updated to include the `getDesnityTemplate` sub

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If that's your method's signature:

> ```
> Private Function getDensityTemplate(FilePath As String) As Workbook
> ```

Then the `FilePath` argument is not optional, therefore **must** be supplied at the call site for the code to compile.

```
Set wb = getDensityTemplate("c:\dev\excel\...\somefile.xlsx")
```

Or whatever the `FilePath` needs to be.

When you invoke a parameterized procedure, be it a `Sub`, `Function`, or `Property`, all non-optional parameters must be specified at the call site in order for the call to be valid.

```
Sub Test()
    DoSomething 42 'illegal: arg2 is missing
End Sub

Sub DoSomething(ByVal arg1 As Long, ByVal arg2 As String)
    'do something
End Sub
```

The only time you can skip specifying parameters is when the parameters are *optional*, e.g.:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal arg1 As Long, Optional ByVal arg2 As String = "SomeDefault")
    'do something
End Sub
```

In which case the procedure with the optional parameters would be implemented in such a way that it can deal with the parameter being unspecified. If you're implementing a procedure with optional parameters, you can verify if a `Variant` parameter was supplied using the `IsMissing` function:

```
Sub DoSomething(ByVal arg1 As Long, Optional ByVal arg2 As Variant)
    If IsMissing(arg2) Then
        'arg2 was not supplied and has no value
    Else
        'arg2 was supplied
    End If
End Sub
```