# Modifying Ron de Bruin Merge Workbook Code for Multiple Ranges?

Tags: excel, merge, range, vba

I was doing some research for a project and came across [some code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0mrj.png) from Ron de Bruin for merging multiple workbooks. It works quite well - you put the excel files you want in a folder on your desktop, run the code, and it combines each workbook into a single excel summary - basically I'm using it for data collection purposes.

The problem I'm having is that I can't seem to specify more than one range without messing up the summary page.

For example, these are the two workbooks/data sets I'm looking to combine:

[Workbook 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0mrj.png)

[Workbook 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fozjH.png)

The final summary result should look like this:

[Should Look Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yC45M.png)

However, the summary currently looks like this:

[Results Currently Look Like This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wr285.png)

The code and attachments for review are below:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/0Bwx3ybze4rlWM3FZZHREWEh2T00?usp=sharing

The problem comes when I specify multiple ranges with this section:

```
Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:G2", "A7:G8")
```

Note also that if you want to test this on your computer, you will need to modify the section you've put the folder with the files to be uploaded:

```
'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
MyPath = "D:\Transfer\Transfer Test\"
```

---

```
Sub MergeAllWorkbooks()
    Dim MyPath As String, FilesInPath As String
    Dim MyFiles() As String
    Dim SourceRcount As Long, FNum As Long
    Dim mybook As Workbook, BaseWks As Worksheet
    Dim sourceRange As Range, destrange As Range
    Dim rnum As Long, CalcMode As Long

    'Fill in the path\folder where the files are
    MyPath = "D:\Budget Transfer\Transfer Test\"

    'Add a slash at the end if the user forget it
    If Right(MyPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        MyPath = MyPath & "\"
    End If

    'If there are no Excel files in the folder exit the sub
    FilesInPath = Dir(MyPath & "*.xl*")
    If FilesInPath = "" Then
        MsgBox "No files found"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    'Fill the array(myFiles)with the list of Excel files in the folder
    FNum = 0
    Do While FilesInPath <> ""
        FNum = FNum + 1
        ReDim Preserve MyFiles(1 To FNum)
        MyFiles(FNum) = FilesInPath
        FilesInPath = Dir()
    Loop

    'Change ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Add a new workbook with one sheet
    Set BaseWks = Workbooks.Add(xlWBATWorksheet).Worksheets(1)
    'First Row of Target Spreadsheet is Blank
    rnum = 1

    'Loop through all files in the array(myFiles)
    If FNum > 0 Then
        ' This section modified from original Ron de Bruin code to include individual items outside range per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718110/create-separate-row-for-each-item-when-merging-multiple-workbooks
        For FNum = LBound(MyFiles) To UBound(MyFiles)
            Set mybook = Nothing
            On Error Resume Next
            Set mybook = Workbooks.Open(MyPath & MyFiles(FNum))
            On Error GoTo 0

            If Not mybook Is Nothing Then
                With mybook.Worksheets(1)
                    Set sourceRange = .Range("A1:G2", "A7:G8")

                    SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count

                    If rnum + SourceRcount >= BaseWks.Rows.Count Then
                        MsgBox "There are not enough rows in the target worksheet."
                        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
                        mybook.Close savechanges:=False
                        GoTo ExitTheSub
                    Else

                        ' Copy the file name in column A. "+1" indicates that the data on the destination sheet is shifted down one row
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "A").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = MyFiles(FNum)
                        ' Copy information from an indivudual cell outside of a range such as date/time started, start/final temp, and Batch ID
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "B").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("K1").Value
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "C").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("K2").Value
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "D").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("K3").Value
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "E").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("K4").Value
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "F").Resize(SourceRcount).Value = .Range("K5").Value
                        'Copy main data
                        BaseWks.Cells(rnum + 1, "G").Resize(SourceRcount, sourceRange.Columns.Count).Value = sourceRange.Value

                        sourceRange.Copy

                        'Set the destrange (this code is part of the code that copies and pastes formats)this is part of the original Ron de Bruin code and not part of YowE3k revision on Stackoverflow
                        Set destrange = BaseWks.Range("G" & rnum + 1)

                        'this code copies and pastes formats per https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s3/win008.htm
                        With destrange
                            .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                            .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                            Application.CutCopyMode = False
                        End With

                        rnum = rnum + SourceRcount
                    End If
                End With
            End If
            mybook.Close savechanges:=False

        Next FNum
        ' This line above finishes the modified code to include individual items outside range per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46718110/create-separate-row-for-each-item-when-merging-multiple-workbooks
        BaseWks.Columns.AutoFit
    End If

ExitTheSub:
    'Restore ScreenUpdating, Calculation and EnableEvents
    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
        .Calculation = CalcMode
    End With
End Sub
```

The original code caused some of the range to not display. After modifying the code using some of YowE3K's code below, the ranges now display on the summary, but I am having an issue where the range I've specified is now pulling in blank rows between the two ranges.

I've read that specifying a range like .Range("A1:G2", "A7:G8") is the equivalent of specifying a range of A1:G8, and that two separate ranges need to be specified as "A1:G2 , A7:G8", but this does not work, so I am at a loss. How can the code be fixed to remove the blank rows between these two ranges? I am not very familiar with macros, so I am not too sure where the specific issue is occurring.

Comment: Is this something like [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46718110/6535336)?

Comment: FWIW - a "quick and nasty" solution would seem to be to change `SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count` to `SourceRcount = sourceRange.Rows.Count * 2` and `Resize(.Rows.Count)` to `Resize(SourceRcount)` (to allow for the two identically shaped `Areas` within `SourceRange`), but I would suggest you look at the other question and then change your code to specifically copy the cells you want to copy to the destination addresses you want to copy them to, and keep track of the destination row correctly.

Comment: Hi @YowE3K, I had a chance to try some of the revised code in the other post. The other poster's problem is similar but not quite the same. He was trying to pull in individual cells as part of the summary report and organize it into a list. This seems like a useful feature so I've used the code here. Using this revised code fixes my original issue of the second range not showing up. However, the summary is now pulling in the blank lines between the two specified ranges, and I am unsure of why or how to correct this. I've updated the screenshots and code in my post. Can you take a look?

Answer (score 0):

Before running the merge functions, organize the data so it is in a single range on each sheet.  Based on your example data, the easiest way is to sort columns A:G.  This will put all the data together.  Once you get it working manually, a line or two of [code can sort](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-sort-method-excel) automatically when you run the merge.